# Example of infinite group with infinitely many simple subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

What is an example of an infinite group with a composition series and infinitely many simple subgroups?

Answer (score 0):

One example is the direct sum of all the finite simple groups (more precisely, pick one for each isomorphism class).

Another (perhaps less cheat-y) one is the group of permutations of $\mathbb N$, which contains all the alternating groups $A_n$ as subgroups.

Comment: first doesn't quite work (composition series are generally finite), but the second is fine.

Comment: Why is the composition series in the second case finite?  Also, to be clear, you mean *all* permuations of $\mathbb{N}$ or only the finitely supported ones?  (Or does it matter?)

Comment: @JasonDeVito: only matters a little. both have composition series of finite length, but different lengths. Alt(finitary) <= Sym(finitary) <= Sym(all N) or so, I believe. Scott's Group Theory textbook has a nice description of composition series of symmetric groups of infinite sets.

Comment: I see - I think the part I was missing was that $A_{\text{finitary}}$ is also simple.